# Felt like/as if I was

Tags: difference

> I felt as if I was about to die.

Vs

> I felt like I was about to die.

What’s the difference? 
Which one’s better?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in contexts involving ***to feel*** used in this way, it's very often *possible* (though not necessarily *stylistically preferable*) to discard the ***as if / like I was*** component entirely. Thus *I felt as if I was unwelcome = I felt like I was unwelcome = **I felt unwelcome***. I can't explain exactly why the shorter version works fine with ***unwelcome, stupid*** (or longer expressions such as ***talking too loudly***), but doesn't work so well with ***about to die*** (and doesn't work at all with, say, ***dying***).

Answer (score 1):

Many textbooks on "proper" English dismiss **like** in that usage as unacceptable or too colloquial, and insist on **as if** instead.  That said, the majority of  native speakers would use **like** in that context.  But be aware that a few native speakers (and perhaps even a standardized testing organization) might consider **like** to be the wrong choice in this context.

They both mean here that the feeling you had seemed to you similar to the feeling you would have if you were expecting to die.  It felt more or less the same.

Sometimes speakers use this phrase when speaking of their own embarrassment in a situation, and in that case it is an exaggeration, and figurative. But it could just as easily be used literally, for example, by someone who was being suffocated by some noxious chemical in a factory disaster.

Comment: Let's not mention the subjunctive!

Comment: Especially if OP didn't ask about it.